# Can I re-ask a foreign question, if the answers aren't sufficient enough for me?

Tags: discussion, answers, duplicate-questions

User A asks a question, user B answers it and A marks B's answer as accepted.
I however realize that B's answer is not entirely wrong but is totally not solving the issue for me.

How and where can I state my problem, how can I ask for further information, how can I make the stack-community re-think this question from a different angle?

- I could comment on B's answer, but this would make just him think
  about it. This will also not un-mark his/her answer as accepted.
- I could edit the question of A and state *"Edited by Blauhirn: The given solution may be working, but lacks the following problem: **...**"*. Is this how edits are supposed to be used? It seems to me I should be commenting on A's question instead, but this will again not bump the entire question.
- I could re-ask the question myself and include *"The question was already answered **here**, but it is not working for me."* But since I'd basically be asking the same question again, it would get marked as duplicate.

Commenting is never satisfying anyway, for the commented post's author could be inactive.

---

edit: I flagged this very question as duplicate because I just found a similar one